# Sample insert into statement aws timestream DB

Tags: amazon-timestream

Is there any sample insert into statement available to insert data to aws timestream tables. I am getting invalid syntax error.

Also aws documentation only provides samples with programming languages (Java,GO,Node,python) not SQL

Answer (score 2):

AWS Timestream does not support the INSERT or any DDL and DML SQL statements. Data insertion into AWS Timestream is supported using AWS SDK.

Answer (score 2):

Inserts are currently (Dec 29 2022) supported via the [`WriteRecords`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/timestream/latest/developerguide/API_WriteRecords.html) API only, which can either be called directly via the SDK, or via the CLI.

Below are two examples for inserting records via the CLI ([reference](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/timestream-write/write-records.html)), and what the resulting entries in the table will look like. For examples using the API, best refer to the [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/timestream/latest/developerguide/code-samples.write.html) as that provides code samples in various programming languages.

**"Single-measure" record insert**

```bash
aws timestream-write write-records \
    --database-name mydatabase \
    --table-name mytable \
    --records '[{"Dimensions":[{"DimensionValueType": "VARCHAR","Name": "device-id","Value": "abc123"}],"MeasureName":"temperature","MeasureValue":"98.76","TimeUnit":"SECONDS","Time":"1672329484"}]'
```

| device-id | measure_name | time | measure_value::double |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc123 | temperature_celsius | 2022-12-30 07:32:36.000000000 | 12.34 |

**"Multie-measure" record insert**

```bash
aws timestream-write write-records \
    --database-name ab3-sensordata \
    --table-name test1 \
    --common-attributes '{"Dimensions":[{"Name": "device-id","Value": "abc123"}],"TimeUnit":"SECONDS","Time":"1672272000000"}' \
    --records '[{"MeasureName":"device-data", "MeasureValueType":"MULTI","MeasureValues":[{"Name":"temperature_celsius", "Type":"DOUBLE", "Value":"12.34"},{"Name":"noise_decibel", "Type":"DOUBLE", "Value":"25.34"}]}]'
```

| device-id | measure_name | time | temperature_celsius | temperature_celsius |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc123 | device-data | 2022-12-30 07:21:20.000000000 | 12.34 | 25.34 |